# ExecuteNonQuery requires an open Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I get the error

> ExecuteNonQuery kräver en öppen och tillgänglig Connection.
>   Anslutningens aktuella status är stängd.

When trying to run my code. I thought I opened  and closed the connection accordingly

```
string connetionString = null;
                SqlConnection connection;
                SqlCommand command;
                SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                XmlReader xmlFile;
                string sql = null;

        connetionString = "Data Source=tsrv2062;Initial Catalog=Bums;User ID=BumsUser;Password=2tusen7Bums";

        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("navetout.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);


        connection.Open();

        DateTime datum = DateTime.Now;

        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Seamen SET FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName, NationalRegistrationCountyCode = @NationalRegistrationCountyCode, NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = @NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode, CitizenshipCode = @CitizenshipCode, LastChangedDate = @LastChangedDate WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber", connection);

        for (int i = 0; i < PersonalIdentityNumber.Count; i++)
        {

            var personnummer = PersonalIdentityNumber[i];
            var fornamn = FirstName[i];
            var efternamn = LastName[i];
            var lankod = LanKod[i];
            var kommunkod = Kommunkod[i];
            //var utdelAdress2 = UtdelAdress2[i];
            //var postNr = PostNr[i];
            //var postOrt = PostOrt[i];
            //var fodelselanKod = FodelselanKod[i];
            //var fodelseforsamling = Fodelseforsamling[i];
            var medborgarskapslandKod = MedborgarskapslandKod[i];
            // var medborgarskapsdatum = Medborgarskapsdatum[i];


            command1.Parameters.Clear();
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", personnummer);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", fornamn);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", efternamn);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCountyCode", lankod);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode", kommunkod);
            //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2", utdelAdress2);
            //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationPostCode", postNr);
            //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCity", postOrt);
            //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthCountyCode", fodelselanKod);
            //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthParish", fodelseforsamling);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipCode", medborgarskapslandKod);
            // command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipDate", medborgarskapsdatum);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastChangedDate", datum);



            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine(personnummer);



        connection.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Can anyone find what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your `connection.Close()` appears to be in a loop, because you forgot a closing brace. Only the first iteration succeeds, and the second one fails due to closed connection.

However, do not rush to add the brace and consider it fixed. This would not be a good way of addressing the problem, because a different issue would remain - you would need to deal with closing the connection on an exception.

C# provides a solution to this - it's the `using` construct. You should fix it like this:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString)) {
    connection.Open();
    ... // Rest of your code; Do not call connection.Close()
}
```

Since `connection` is enclosed in `using`, the program will close it automatically upon exiting the `using` block. It will do so upon normal exit, but also upon exiting on an exception, so you do not have to worry about catching, closing, and re-throwing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the true advice of dasblinkenlight put your closing connections out of for loop  and at the end of for loop put a command1.parameters.clear (You have to clear old parameters)

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you have posted is missing a close brace for the `for` loop - it should be immediately following the `Console.WriteLine(personnummer);` but if it is not then the following line which closes the connection will be inside the `for` loop and the connection will be closed following the first iteration, causing the error on the second iteration.